# Error when attempting Choropleth map using Folium on Python

Tags: python, dictionary, choropleth, folium

**I've been working on a map showing crime rate in different San Fransisco Neighbourhoods using Folium Choropleth Maps.**

The geojson file I am using is:
https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson and I have saved this as 'data'

And the data I am using is from:
https://cocl.us/sanfran_crime_dataset and I have saved this as 'cdata'.

My code is as follows;

```
cdata.rename(columns={'PdDistrict':'Neighbourhood'}, inplace=True)

neighbourhood = cdata.groupby(['Neighbourhood']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
```

to obtain:

```
  Neighbourhood     Count
0   BAYVIEW         14303
1   CENTRAL         17666
2   INGLESIDE       11594
3   MISSION         19503
4   NORTHERN        20100
5   PARK            8699
6   RICHMOND        8922
7   SOUTHERN        28445
8   TARAVAL         11325
9   TENDERLOIN      9942
```

Then I use:

```
sanfran = folium.Map(location=[37.7749, -122.4194], zoom_start = 12)
sanfran.choropleth(
    geo_data=dat,
    name='choropleth',
    data=neighbourhood,
    columns=['Neighbourhood', 'Count'],
    key_on='properties.DISTRICT',
    fill_color='YlOrRd',
    fill_opacity = 0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Crime Rate in San Francisco')
```

When I run the sanfran.choropleth code, I get the following error:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\folium.py:432: FutureWarning: The choropleth  method has been deprecated. Instead use the new Choropleth class, which has the same arguments. See the example notebook 'GeoJSON_and_choropleth' for how to do this.
FutureWarning
```

And then if i just type 'sanfran' and run the code I get:

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

Would really appreciate some help with this, thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? "unhashable type: 'list'" might be due to several things.

Comment: The warning you are getting tells you that you should use the class `Chorophlet` instead of the method `chorophlet`. Check this [link](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb) on how to do this: go to the section "Using Chorophlet class" (cell `In [15]`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a change made in the syntax.

Call Choropleth with capital 'C' on folium and chain 'add_to(map)' method passing the name of your map like so

```
folium.Choropleth(all your arguments as the old method).add_to(map)
```

Check this link and scroll down to the section on Choropleth maps for details.
https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Getting-Started

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run and create a map, you should follow the new syntax of folium.
Your code should be like this:

```
sanfran = folium.Map(location=[37.7749, -122.4194], zoom_start=12)
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=dat,
    name='choropleth',
    data=neighbourhood,
    columns=['Neighbourhood', 'Count'],
    key_on='properties.DISTRICT',
    fill_color='YlOrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Crime Rate in San Francisco').add_to(sanfran)

sanfran.save('outfile.html')
```